# Bucketing Data, If Bucket Size Greater Then 1 Set Value To 1 Else 0

Tags: sql, count, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions, snowsql

I'm using `snowflake` to attempt to bucket rows based on two columns and if that bucket size is greater then 1 then I need the value of of some new column to be 1, otherwise I would set it to 0. It's similar to `NTILE()` except that I would need this to be dynamic.

The table that I have looks like the following:

```
ARTICLE_ID      USER_ID     COUNTRY_NAME    NUM_COUNTRIES   NUM_AUTHORS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
30522143        ecf330d     Singapore       1               4
30522143        86b0faa     Singapore       1               4
30522143        d331b33     Singapore       1               4
30522143        d331b33     Singapore       1               4
------------------------------------------------------------------------
30522139        1d08cfd     United States   2               3
30522139        ec9c065     Canada          2               3
30522139        a750bff     United States   2               3
------------------------------------------------------------------------
23410385        1d08cfd     United States   3               3
23410385        ec9c065     Mexico          3               3
23410385        a41b19c     France          3               3
------------------------------------------------------------------------
30285132        d331b33     Chile           2               4
30285132        1d08cf2     Peru            2               4
30285132        a750bff     Chile           2               4
30285132        d742bb5     Peru            2               4
------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

The two columns that I would need to bucket are by `ARTICLE_ID` then `COUNTRY_NAME`. Looking at the above table if we take `ARTICLE_ID` `30522143` we would have `1` bucket of `4` `USER_ID` since they are all `Singapore` then the value of `HAS_REPEATED_COUNTRY` would be 1.

In the case of `ARTICLE_ID` `30522139` we would have two sub-buckets one for `United States` containing `2` `USER_ID`s and another sub-bucket `(Canada)` containing `1` `USER_ID` which would result in all those users associated with `United States` to have a value of `1` and the sole member associated with `Canada` to have a value of `0` in `HAS_REPEATED_COUNTRY`.

Hence the table would resemble:

```
ARTICLE_ID      USER_ID     COUNTRY_NAME    NUM_COUNTRIES   NUM_AUTHORS     HAS_REPEATED_COUNTRY
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
30522143        ecf330d     Singapore       1               4               1
30522143        86b0faa     Singapore       1               4               1
30522143        d331b33     Singapore       1               4               1
30522143        d331b33     Singapore       1               4               1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
30522139        1d08cfd     United States   2               3               1
30522139        ec9c065     Canada          2               3               0
30522139        a750bff     United States   2               3               1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
23410385        1d08cfd     United States   3               3               0
23410385        ec9c065     Mexico          3               3               0
23410385        a41b19c     France          3               3               0
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
30285132        d331b33     Chile           2               4               1
30285132        1d08cf2     Peru            2               4               1
30285132        a750bff     Chile           2               4               1
30285132        d742bb5     Peru            2               4               1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

Is there any way of producing the latter table from the former?

Comment: Should be a simple *Windowed Aggregate*: `case when count(*) over (partition by ARTICLE_ID, COUNTRY_NAME) > 1 then 1 else 0 end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you want to flag countries that appear more than once for a given article. If so, you can just use a window count:

```
select 
    t.*,
    case when count(*) over(partition by article_id, country_name) > 1
        then 1 else 0
    end as has_repeated_country
from mytable t
```